# Histogram showing twice the probabilities

Tags: probability, histogram, matplotlib

I have this list of numbers:

```
D = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
     50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
     50, 50, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Here,

- 100 occurs 10% of time
- 50 occurs 30% of time
- 1 occurs 60% of time

My histogram shows 2x probabilities when I plot it:

```
plt.hist(D, bins=range(0, 110, 5), edgecolor='black', density=True)
```

[image]

Shouldn't it be `0.6, 0.3` and `0.1` for bars?

Comment: Your bin width is set to 5 due to the last argument in range(0, 110, 5). The first bar shows a density of 0.12 on the y-axis, the second 0.06 and the last 0.02. Note that 5 * (0.12 + 0.06 + 0.02) = 1, which is the total probability (width * density). So this plot is correct. It's just not what you were expecting. Perhaps change it to range(0, 110, 1) or play around with the density=True argument.

Comment: Okay, I see. I had set it to '5' because I thought it was like setting "bin width". With '1' I get very thin bars. Any solution to make bars width bigger while correctly displaying probability? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, this listing of the data seems to be sorted with larger values first. So there is no telling whether it is a random sample from any particular distribution.

In most statistical software programs you have a choice whether the vertical axis of the histogram shows frequencies or somehow expresses proportions of the whole,
what bin boundaries to use, etc.

Here are examples for the procedure `hist` in the base of R:

```
D = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
      50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
     50, 50, 50, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 hist(D, label=T, br=seq(-5,109, by=10), col="skyblue2")
 hist(D, prob=T, br=c(0, 49, 99, 149), col="wheat")
 hist(D, prob=T, br=0:101, col="grey")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

The vertical scale of a 'Density' histogram is made
so that the areas of all the bars sum to $1.$

Using a density histogram, you can plot the population density function along with the histogram.

```
set.seed(2020)
y = rnorm(1000, 100, 10)
hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve(dnorm(x, 100, 10), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]
Whatever software you use, you should read the documentation to see find the options available.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the axis closely it looks like the values are actually 0.2x what you expect. Is that because each bar has width 5? Maybe using range(0, 110, 1) would give you the bar heights you expect?

Comment: Thanks. Yes '1' works but the bar width becomes very small as well. Any idea on keeping width about the same and still being correct?

Comment: A histogram where the bin width is 5 and the bar heights are 0.6, 0.3, and 0.1 would actually be incorrect, since the total probability mass associated with a bin is the product of the height and width of its bar. Since your data seem to take a small set of discrete values (1, 50, 100), you could use a bar chart rather than a histogram.